# Where can I buy Majo x Kamikakushi?

Tags: majo-x-kamikakushi, spain

A while ago, I learned that the author of a manga I loved died but that its artist (Katou Yoshie) was still in business. One of the manga he/she's working on is named *Majo x Kamikakushi*, but I haven't had luck finding anywhere to buy it.

Could anyone help me figure out where I buy it? Apparently it's serialized in Gangan magazine.

Comment: Well, I guess it may be hard to find it in spain.

Comment: It seems this isn't just hard to find in Spain, but pretty much everywhere outside Japan. According to Baka Updates it's not even being scanlated. There's no Wikipedia entry, no MyAnimeList entry, no Anime News Network entry. It's not listed under Yoshie Katou's MyAnimeList page. The only evidence I found that it even exists was on some Italian blog that just listed all the manga currently running in Shounen Gangan. Unfortunately, I think the only way you can read this is to buy the Japanese edition of Shounen Gangan or the Japanese tankoubon and learn to read Japanese.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [Torisuda's comment](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/28950/where-can-i-buy-majo-x-kamikakushi#comment43400_28950), it seems there's not much info about this manga, even in Japanese. (There's no Wikipedia article, etc.)

Also, there doesn't seem any tankobon for this series. Considering this, the best/only way to read it is by buying the Gangan magazines themselves.

According to [Japanese Wikipedia's article for Monthly Shonen Gangan](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%9C%88%E5%88%8A%E5%B0%91%E5%B9%B4%E3%82%AC%E3%83%B3%E3%82%AC%E3%83%B3), *Majo x Kamikakushi* was published in 2015/02 - 2015/04. Searching for those back issues, I only found them on Amazon Japan (not new, but used items):

- [Monthly Shonen Gangan 2015/02](https://www.amazon.co.jp/%E5%B0%91%E5%B9%B4%E3%82%AC%E3%83%B3%E3%82%AC%E3%83%B3-2015%E5%B9%B4-2%E6%9C%88%E5%8F%B7/dp/B00R0U2DN0)
- [Monthly Shonen Gangan 2015/03](https://www.amazon.co.jp/%E5%B0%91%E5%B9%B4%E3%82%AC%E3%83%B3%E3%82%AC%E3%83%B3-2015%E5%B9%B4-3%E6%9C%88%E5%8F%B7/dp/B00S0NB1QG)
- [Monthly Shonen Gangan 2015/04](https://www.amazon.co.jp/%E5%B0%91%E5%B9%B4%E3%82%AC%E3%83%B3%E3%82%AC%E3%83%B3-2015%E5%B9%B4-4-%E6%9C%88%E5%8F%B7/dp/B00STR3NCS)

Comment: I believe the detail on how to buy it from Amazon Japan and deliver it to your address is off-topic, so I won't include it in here. Also, it depends on your country, whereas I try to make this answer as general as possible.